# Azure Pricing Details Api

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-virtual-machine

As in AWS, we can get the pricing details just by hitting this api (https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json), so is there any simpler way we can get the pricing for different instances in Azure.

I am able to find this API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices

But this does not lists the instances details.
As the pricing for different VM's is clearly mentioned over here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/virtual-machines/windows/), so can we get these details progrmatically by any API ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no unified API, you'd have to get the SKUs from this authenticated API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resourceskus/list

And then join them to the matching azure retail price